# How to set an application to be open in max window size?

Tags: macos

I want to set that by default an application I open (specifically Preview) will be opened in maximum window size.
Note that I do not want it to be in full screen. I want the window to take the maximum size - leaving room for the top-bar and the dock.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: **Preview** (and or **macOS**) does not have a _preference_ that can be set to achieve what you request.

Comment: Are you open to install any third-party softwares using `brew`? If so, then you might try tiling window managers, which would allow you to open your apps in max window size by default.

Comment: How do you open an application (Spotlight, clicking, terminal etc)?

Answer (score 3):

As **Preview** (and or **macOS**) does not have a *preference setting* that always opens *windows* of an *application* in *full desktop* (not to be confused with *full screen*), here is an alternate answer that provides for a *keyboard shortcut* in **Preview** to resize the frontmost *window* in **Preview**.

This uses no *third-party* anything and can be done using **macOS** default *applications* and some **AppleScript** *code* without having to mess with **System Integrity Protection**.

Create an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action* with settings as shown in the image further below.

Add a **Run AppleScript** *action* replacing the default *code* with the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "Finder" to ¬
    set {missing value, missing value, ¬
        desktopWidth, desktopHeight} to ¬
        the bounds of window of desktop

tell application "System Events" to ¬
    tell application process "Finder" to ¬
        set {missing value, menubarHeight} to ¬
            the size of menu bar 1

tell application "System Events" to ¬
    tell application process "Dock" to ¬
        set {missing value, dockHeight} to ¬
            the size of list 1

tell application "Preview" to ¬
    if (exists front window) then ¬
        set bounds of front window to ¬
            {0, menubarHeight + 1, desktopWidth, ¬
                desktopHeight - dockHeight}
```

Assign it a *keyboard shortcut* in: **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**

I used **⌥⌘F** as it is not currently assigned in **Preview**.

---

Testing in **macOS Catalina**, the first time I used it I had to click the **OK** *button* on the message box shown below.

[image: Preview permissions]

---

[image: Automator Quick Action]

---

**Notes:**

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* shown above assumes the **Dock** is always visible and additional coding is required if the **Dock** is hidden.

If you are one that likes to have the **Dock** hidden, then use the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* instead of the previous *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "Finder" to ¬
    set {missing value, missing value, ¬
        desktopWidth, desktopHeight} to ¬
        the bounds of window of desktop

tell application "System Events" to ¬
    tell application process "Finder" to ¬
        set {missing value, menubarHeight} to ¬
            the size of menu bar 1

tell application "System Events" to ¬
    tell application process "Dock" to ¬
        set {missing value, dockHeight} to ¬
            the size of list 1

tell application "System Events" to ¬
    set dockIsHidden to ¬
        autohide of dock preferences

if dockIsHidden then
    set windowHeight to desktopHeight
else
    set windowHeight to desktopHeight - dockHeight
end if

tell application "Preview" to ¬
    if (exists front window) then ¬
        set bounds of front window to ¬
            {0, menubarHeight + 1, ¬
                desktopWidth, windowHeight}
```

If by chance you want this to act on all *windows* in **Preview** then change the `tell application "Preview"` *command* as the last *command* in the *code* to the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
tell application "Preview" to ¬
    if (exists windows) then ¬
        set bounds of windows to ¬
            {0, menubarHeight + 1, ¬
                desktopWidth, windowHeight}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

Here is one solution to this, which is using a tiling window manager called `yabai`.

Look at their git repo at: https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai

**Note**: It requires some advance settings to be configured in `SIP` and requires `yabai` to be installed with scripting addition.
If you do not want to mess around with System Integrity Protection, then see **Solution 2** instead.

**Prerequisite**

- Homebrew
- SIP configuration

> System Integrity Protection needs to be (partially) disabled for yabai
> to inject a scripting addition into Dock.app for controlling windows
> with functions that require elevated privileges. This enables control
> of the window server, which is the sole owner of all window
> connections, and enables additional features of yabai. If you are
> running on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6, you can reenable SIP after the
> scripting addition has been installed.

- In the Mission Control preferences pane in System Preferences, the setting "Displays have separate Spaces" must be enabled.
- In the Mission Control preferences pane in System Preferences, the setting "Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use" should be disabled for commands that rely on the ordering of spaces to work reliably.

More details at: https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai

**Homebrew**

Install `homebrew` if you do not have it already by copying and pasting the following in your terminal.

```bsh
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

**SIP configuration**

Boot in recovery mode and execute the following in the terminal:

```bsh
csrutil enable --without debug --without fs
# after executing the above reboot
reboot
```

**Install `yabai` with scripting addition**

Install by:

```bsh
brew install koekeishiya/formulae/yabai
# install the scripting addition
sudo yabai --install-sa

# if macOS Big Sur, load the scripting addition manually; follow instructions below to automate on startup
sudo yabai --load-sa
```

For details see their official installation guide [here](https://github.com/koekeishiya/yabai/wiki/Installing-yabai-(latest-release))

**Start `yabai`**

```bsh
# start yabai
brew services start yabai
```

Now, when you open an app in an empty window, it will always open with maximum window size. However, if there are two apps in one window, each will take half of the window, so on and so forth. If you want one specific app to be with maximum size, I recommend using <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to hide those apps, allowing your intended app to take maximum size automatically. To navigate the hidden apps use <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>

If you want to stop `yabai`, stop it by:

```bsh
brew services stop yabai
```

**Solution 2:**

Use keyboard-centric apps like `spectacle`, `skhd` `rectangle` etc to resize apps by using keyboard shortcuts instead.

Spectacle (easiest): `brew install --cask spectacle`

rectangle (easiest): `brew install --cask rectangle`

skhd (works well with `yabai`): `brew install koekeishiya/formulae/skhd && brew services start skhd`